# how to prevent live wallpapaer service orientation change

Tags: android

I developed the bubble-dictionary live wallpaper and is working fine, but when I change orientation on my  mobile android canvas, it give error `illegal argument exception`, so I want to have fixed orientation of my wallpaper service. Any one can please help me how to fixed the orientation of live wallpaper service my `Manifest` file have follwoing its not have any screen `orientation` for service tag so please tell me how to do this

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:name="com.packageService.android.samplesV1.SampleLiveWallpaperService"
        android:label="@string/liveWallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/sample_livewallpaper" />
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.packageService.android.samplesV1.ColorSettings"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: i dont want to change orientation , i want to fixed orientation of potrait of my livewallpapaer service, but through my try it not possible with service so how to do fixed orientation of portrait of service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont find solution for screen orientation change of service but if we want to remove exception illegal argument exception do follwoing in finally block ( simply `holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` put in try and catch block )

```
finally {
    if (canvas != null) {
        try {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            } 
                            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```